# Upgrading Unity to 5.11.1

Tags: unity-container

I'm trying do upgrade Unity from version 3.0.1304.1 to the latest, 5.11.1. Unsurprisingly, there are some issues (3.0.1304.1 is quite old). The code below accomplished two things:

1. Use a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager for all classes deriving from some base class X, without specifying that for every class derived from X.
2. Use the default constructor when resolving for all classes deriving from base class Y, without specifying that for every class derived from Y.

Unity documentation is scarce nowadays, and lacks examples. I've read the [upgrade notes](https://unitycontainer.github.io/articles/changelog.html) and regular documentation but I can't make this work with the new version.

So far I have:

- Replaced `IConstructorSelectorPolicy` with `ISelect<ConstructorInfo>`
- Replaced `IBuilderContext` with `BuilderContext` (or ref BuilderContext in the PreBuildUp function)

But what to do with the `LifetimeManagerFactory`? Should I derive `IOCConstructorSelectorPolicy` from `ISelect<ConstructorInfo>` and should `IOCConstructorSelectorPolicy.SelectConstructor` then be replaced by `Select` (as per the ISelect interface) and how to implement this Select function?

I know this is a very long shot, and I'll post this on the unity github as well (as a request for documentation of sorts), but hopefully there is someone who can give me some pointers.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This class merely exists for readability: avoid having to write the class it derives from.
    /// </summary>
    public class IOCConfigLifetimeExtension : DefaultLifetimeManagerExtension<ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, X>
    {}

    /// <summary>
    /// An IOC strategy to use a specific LifetimeManager (<typeparamref name="TLifetimeManager"/>) for subclasses of <typeparamref name="TBaseClass"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class DefaultLifetimeManagerExtension<TLifetimeManager, TBaseClass> : UnityContainerExtension where TLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager, new()
    {
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            var theFactory = new LifetimeManagerFactory(Context, typeof(TLifetimeManager));
            Context.Strategies.Add(new DefaultLifetimeManagerStrategy(theFactory, TypePredicate), UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
        }

         private bool TypePredicate(Type type)
         {
             return typeof (TBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(type);
         }
    }

    public class DefaultLifetimeManagerStrategy : BuilderStrategy
    {
        public DefaultLifetimeManagerStrategy(LifetimeManagerFactory factory, Predicate<Type> typePredicate)
        {
            mFactory = factory;
            mTypePredicate = typePredicate;
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            if (context.Existing == null) {
                var theLifetime = context.Policies.GetNoDefault<ILifetimePolicy>(context.BuildKey, false);

                if (theLifetime == null && mTypePredicate(context.BuildKey.Type)) {
                    theLifetime = mFactory.CreateLifetimePolicy();
                    context.PersistentPolicies.Set(theLifetime, context.BuildKey);
                }
            }
        }
        private readonly LifetimeManagerFactory mFactory;
        private readonly Predicate<Type> mTypePredicate;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Unity extension that prioritizes the default constructor for classes derived of Y when available, otherwise the default resolve method is used.
    /// </summary>
    public class IOCExtension : UnityContainerExtension
    {
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            var theDefaultConstructorSelectorPolicy = Context.Policies.Get<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(null);
            Context.Policies.SetDefault<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(new IOCConstructorSelectorPolicy(theDefaultConstructorSelectorPolicy));
        }

        public class IOCConstructorSelectorPolicy : IConstructorSelectorPolicy
        {
            public IOCConstructorSelectorPolicy(IConstructorSelectorPolicy defaultConstructorSelectorPolicy)
            {
                mDefaultConstructorSelectorPolicy = defaultConstructorSelectorPolicy;
            }

            public SelectedConstructor SelectConstructor(IBuilderContext context, IPolicyList resolverPolicyDestination)
            {
                Type theType = context.BuildKey.Type;
                if (typeof(DataNode).IsAssignableFrom(theType)) {
                    ConstructorInfo theDefaultConstructorInfo = theType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                    if (theDefaultConstructorInfo != null && theDefaultConstructorInfo.IsPublic) {
                        return new SelectedConstructor(theDefaultConstructorInfo);
                    }
                }
                return mDefaultConstructorSelectorPolicy.SelectConstructor(context, resolverPolicyDestination);
            }

            private readonly IConstructorSelectorPolicy mDefaultConstructorSelectorPolicy;
        }
    }
```